# An identity for probability measures following from equality of expectations

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}_n$ be some filtration and $\mathcal{F}_\infty = \bigvee_n \mathcal{F}_n$. Moreover, let $P_n$ be probability measures on $\mathcal{F}_n$ and $P$ a probability measure on $\mathcal{F}_\infty$. My question is whether the following holds and why:

If $E (X_n) = E_n(X_n)$ for every $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable r.v. $X_n$, then $P \vert \mathcal{F}_n = P_n$ for all $n\geq 0$.

Writing $E_n$ for the expectation under $P_n$ and $E$ for the expectation under $P$. I thought if I just choose for $A \in \mathcal{F}_n$ the indicators as random variables, then I would have $P(A) = P_n(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}_n$. But is that enough?

**Edit:** To make things clear, $P \vert \mathcal{F}_n$ denotes the probability measure restricted on $\mathcal{F}_n$.

Comment: $P[A | F_n]$ would be a random variable (it could be defined $E[1_A|F_n]$) so it is not the same type of thing as $P_n[A]$ (which is a number).  So likely $P|F_n$ is supposed to just restrict the probability measure to $F_n$, and your indicator function method then works, it seems to be all that the question was asking.

Comment: I would agree with you that I would ordinarily expect $P|F_n$ to mean $P[\cdot | F_n]$, rather than the restriction (which is what it must mean for the statement of the question to make sense).  I think the person who wrote this question should have clarified the notation.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I agree that only the conditioning makes sense. I edited it

Comment: No, I meant that only the restriction makes sense.  The conditional probability is a different kind of object, not a number. So the only thing that makes sense is for the notation to be interpreted in an unexpected way.

Comment: Oh right... Now I get it. Thanks again.